# Jest test failing and not receiving toHaveBeenCalled from simulated click

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I am having an issue with a Jest test using React.  I am also using Enzyme as well.  Additionally, I am using Redux.

If you see the jest test below you will see two simulated clicks.  The reason for two simulated clicks in my test below is that the inputs inside the "showAddItem" check are both hidden.  Clicking on "div#add_item" allows this div to be visible.  After this, clicking on the "input#add_item_submit" should call the addItemToWatchList.

In my testing using a debugger and running the tests, the first simulated click does set the state to showAddItem to true.  This allows the input "add_item_submit" to be available in the DOM.  After that is shown the second simulated click in the test doesn't seem to fire because the addItemToWatchList doesn't get called.  The output of my test is:

```
    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

relevant react component code:

```
{ this.state.showAddItem ? <div>
   <input type="text" name="watchListItem" value={this.state.watchListItem} 
     onChange={this.handleInputChange}></input><br />
   <input type="submit" id="add_item_submit" value="Add Item" 
     onClick={ () => this.addItemToWatchList()}/>
  </div> : null }
```

relevant Jest/enzyme test

```
it('should call addItemToWatchList when adding a item', () => {
  const initialState = { userReducer: {user: { id: 1, email: "test@test.com"}} }
  const mockStore = configureStore([]);
  const store = mockStore(initialState);
  const component = mount(<Provider store={store}>
      <AddItem />
  </Provider>);
  const mockedAddItemToWatchList = jest.fn();
  component.instance().addItemToWatchList = mockedAddItemToWatchList
  //sets state to showAddItem to true
  component.find('div#add_item').simulate('click')
  component.find('input#add_item_submit').simulate('click')
  expect(mockedAddItemToWatchList).toHaveBeenCalled()
});
```

Just a side note, I also did try doing jest.spyOn without any luck as well.

Answer (score 0):

The   component.instance() might be returning the instance of Provided. You can try mounting AddItem directly an mocking its internal method behaviour.

```js
  const component = mount(
      <AddItem />);
```

Comment: thanks vishnu, unfortunately, this results in an error "Invariant Violation: Could not find “store” in either the context or props of “Connect(AddItem).”  The AddItem component is a redux component that is connected to a redux store.  So, I have to pass in a store.  I did try <AddItem store={store} /> but this is not working.